# Bash (v.2.03) capture awk output to array not working

Tags: bash, awk

I am struggling around with awk and want to save the awk output **separated by the delimiter** to array. So just to have this working:

```
array[index]=$line
```

with `$line` equal value between separator `'[[:blank:]]{2,}'` in the desired file.

I tried already multiple solutions like:

```
myarr=$(/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' 'FNR > 4 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "") print $i;}' my-file)
```

or

```
array=()
counter=0
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' 'FNR > 4 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "") print $i;}' my-file | while read -r line; do
    array[counter]=$line
    counter=$((counter+1))
done

echo ${#array[@]}
echo ${array[1]}
```

none of them produce the desired result. But when I modify the second case and `echo` the `$line` and the `$counter` I get the array, but it is not the case for a large file, I just do not want to output the whole lines to the console to get my array filled up - it makes no sense for me:

**This works -> but uggly/bad performance for large files**

```
array=()
counter=0
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' 'FNR > 4 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "") print $i;}'my-file | while read -r line; do
    echo $line
    echo $counter
    array[counter]=$line
    counter=$((counter+1))
done

echo ${#array[@]}
echo ${array[1]}
```

Comment: Marking as duplicate do not make sense, because I just didn't realize what the problem was, so I could not find the answer using search.

Comment: Sirion: It is not a problem. It is kind of a way to _protect_ the question from welcoming other incorrect answers and letting know that this was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) - I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?

Bash pipe-lines create a sub-shell in which the variables updated are *not* reflected at all. In your case either of your array `array` and `counter` variable scopes are lost soon after the sub-shell terminates. Use [process-substitution(`<( … )`)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) in `bash` as below

Also the array subscript you are using is incorrect; which should have been done as

```
array[$counter]="$line"
```

Combining the two,

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    echo "$counter"
    array[$counter]="$line"
    counter=$((counter+1))
done < <(/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' 'FNR > 4 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "") print $i;}' my-file)
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved (the rest of) my day.